# how can i inject a presenter into a view without the view having a reference to the presenter

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, mvp

in a classic Passive-MVP pattern, how can i avoid a reference of the presenter in my view completely & still inject the presenter instance which needs the view instance as a parameter.

with asp.net as an example:

- my implemented views (web project) should not have a reference to the Presenters. (Neither IPresenter nor the concrete ones)
- when the view instantiates, (basically my web page), the presenter should be instantiated with the current view's reference.
- i am using unity as my ioc container.

right now what i do in the web page's code behind is this:

```
public partial class SomePage : MyBasePage, ISomeView
{
    private readonly ISomePresenter presenter;

    public SomePage()
    {
        this.presenter = ResolveSomeWay(this);
    }
}
```

for this i have a reference of the 'Presenter Contracts DLL' in my view implementation. is there a way to avoid this reference completely & still hook up the presenter with the view instance, when the view instantiates?

i just care about the presenter instantiation, since the presenter's constructor can set the passed parameter-view-instance to its View Property & it subscribes to the view's events, for any future communication.

thanks folks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "publish" a new View was instantiated to a Message Bus, to which a Presenter factory could "bind" the instantiated View to a Presenter. Although the View would be agnostic of the presenter, it would not be of the Message Bus.

```
public partial class SomePage : MyBasePage, ISomeView
{
    // Alternative #1
    public SomePage(IMessageBus messageBus)
    {
        // You publish a message saying that a handler for ISomeView is to handle the
        // message.
        messageBus.Publish<ISomeView>(this);
    }
    // Alternative #2
    public SomePage()
    {
        Resolver.Resolve<IMessageBus>().Publish<ISomeView>(this);
    }
}

// This could be somewhere else in your application (this could be a separate DLL), but 
// I will use the Global.asax.cs here, for simplicity
public void Application_Start()
{
    Container.Resolve<IMessageBus>()
             .Subscribe<ISomeView>(someView => 
                 {
                    var presenter = new SomePresenter(someView);
                 });
}

public interface ISomeView {
    event Action<ISomeView> SomeEvent;
}

public class SomePresenter
{
    public SomePresenter(ISomeView view) {
        // if you attach the presenter to the View event, 
        // the Garbage Collector won't finalize the Presenter until
        // the View is finalized too
        view.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
    }

    private void SomeEventHandler(ISomeView view) { 
       // handle the event
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Marcel. i ended up following the exact second approach.. have a Resolver DLL which basically does IoC across the solution. so the Resolver has references to Presenter interfaces. Resolver.ResolvePresenter<IMyView>(this);

Comment: There are IoC/Dependency Injection containers that allow you to remove the dependencies from the Container itself. You'd merely have to define the constructor, and the Dependency Injection container provides the object with an instance, checkout: Ninject, StructureMap, Windsor Container and Microsoft Unity Container. The Unity Container is extensible, and can be substituted with any of the other containers.